# Set Java-web-start Trace file options from server-end

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

Is there a way to set java web start trace file options (such as location and filename) through the JNLP or some other way from the server as opposed to modifying the deploy.properties file on each user's computer?

Comment: What do you hope to gain from changing the 'location and filename'?  What are you actually trying to **achieve** (as opposed to what are you trying to **do**)?

Comment: What I would like to have is one central, easy to get to, location for all log files if/when a user has issues with the application. They're not exactly "power users".

Comment: See what a good logging framework can do for you!  "one central location" might be many things (database,syslog,XMPP etc.).

Answer (score 1):

No, I do not believe the Java WebStart protocol allows for this through the JNLP file.

If this is for your own logging then just use a logging framework which allow you to log to a given file.

If this is for capturing log output from javaws for forensic analysis then instead instruct the user to set this up in the Java Control Center.  It is just a few clicks.